# Jquery Selectors And Condition

Tags: jquery

We have a requirement in application that on clicking on all images which do not have a css class of "xyz" we want to call a function. We are trying to write it somehwhat like this:

```
$('input[type=image] class=xyz').click(function(){//something});
```

It doesn't seem to work. Ideal scenario would be that all images on clicking does some functionality except the one which has CSS as "xyz".

What am I doing wrong?

**I am using input, as I use JSF and this command button is being displayed as an input type component with src as image.**

Thanks for your help in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to use [not](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/not).

This should do it:

```
$('input[type=image]').not(".xyz").click(function(){//something});
```

You may also be able to use the [not selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not).

```
$('input[type=image]:not(.xyz)').click(function(){//something});
```

The function version seems more expressive to me.

Answer (score 1):

> We have a requirement in application that on clicking on all images which do not have a css class of "xyz" we want to call a function.

That should be pretty intuitive using JQuery:

- Select all images
- Filter out those which match your CSS class

Code:

```
$('input[type=image],img').not('.xyz').click(myFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can remove elements from selection having certain class or id using **not** function:

```
$("input[type=image]").not(".xyz").click(function(){....});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('input[type=image][class!=xyz]').click(function(){//something});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('input[type=image]:not(.xyz)').click(function(){//something});
```